# How do I return multiple results from a SQL Server Stored Procedure with PHP prepared statements?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

I have an application tied to an SQL Server 2012 instance.  I'm trying to return a record from the main table **tblProjects** and all records from a related table **tblPartners**.  When I execute the stored procedure in SQL Server I get results from both tables:

```
EXEC getProjectDetails @prjID = 14
```

[image]

My stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getProjectDetails @prjID int = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT ProjectID, ProjectTitle, Latitude, Longitude, Acreage, LastModifiedDate, LastModifiedBy, Boundary.STAsText() As Boundary
    FROM tblProjects 
    WHERE ProjectID = @prjID

    SELECT PartnerName As Name, Type, Role, ProjectID
    FROM tblPartners
    WHERE ProjectID = @prjID
END
GO
```

The PHP:

```
<?php
    $prjID = $_GET["prjID"];

    include_once("connection.php");
    $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"$dbname", "UID"=>$user, "PWD"=>$pass);
    $DBH = sqlsrv_connect($server, $connectionInfo);

    if( !$DBH ) {
        echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
    }

    $sql = "{CALL getProjectDetails(?)}";
    $params = array(&$prjID);

    if (!$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($DBH, $sql, $params) ) {
        echo "Statement could not be prepared.\n";
    }

    if ( !$query = sqlsrv_execute( $stmt ) ) {
        echo "Statement could not be executed.\n";
    }

    $result = array();
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
        $result[] = $row;
    }

    print json_encode($result);
```

Resulting output only displays results from the first query:
[image]

I'm new at this; is it possible to get results for more than one table in this or a related way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your store procedure body to:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblProjects 
LEFT JOIN  tblPartners 
ON ( tblProjects.ProjectID = tblPartners.ProjectID  )
WHERE tblProjects.ProjectID = @prjID
```

Comment: I'm looking to select fields from a number of related tables.  I figured I might have to use joins, but I was hoping to avoid them because I'll wind up passing quite a bit of repetitive data between the client-side and database.

Would it be more appropriate to live with all the repetitive data, or rather to create a separate stored procedure for each related table and just make multiple database calls?

Comment: @Roy Sorry, i dont understand you now. I see 2 tables are related by `ProjectID`. "number of related table" - what is means?

Comment: **tblProjects** is my "Main" table, but I have about 10 other tables that have a `ProjectID` foreign key to link the tables (**tblSpecies**, **tblHabitats**, **tblFocalAreas**, etc.).  Let's say, for example, I wanted to get all of the information for a given project.  I'd need to do a `LEFT JOIN` on ~10 tables in the same query, and the result would be a HUGE piece of JSON to send back to the application.

Comment: what a problem if response will be huge? Or very huge?

Comment: I was expecting it to slow down the application, but that's something I'll just have to test.  Thanks!

Comment: do 10 left joins. One question: for me is  very strange DB structure that has 10 tables related by one id? what a reason?